# how to set the maximum and minimum image of MPVolumeView correctly

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uislider, mpvolumeview

i am trying to set the maximum and minimum image of MPVolumeView but i can't get it working

here is the code

```
VolumeView.setVolumeThumbImage(UIImage(named: "VolumeSlider"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
VolumeView.setMinimumVolumeSliderImage(UIImage(named: "VolumeUp"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
VolumeView.setMaximumVolumeSliderImage(UIImage(named: "VolumeDown"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

and here is the result
[image]
does any one had this problem before , any help will be great ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you have written is fine, however, you misunderstood what `setMinimumVolumeSliderImage` and `setMaximumVolumeSliderImage` achieve. These methods are for actually setting the track images of the control.

You're looking for something comparable to `minimumValueImage` and `maximumValueImage` on `UISlider`. Unfortunately, `MPVolumeView` doesn't have such methods.

The only work around would be to position a `UIImageView` either side of the volume view to show your images. The downside to this is that the route button will get in the way for the maximum value image, so you would have to set `showsRouteButton = NO;` to prevent this.

Comment: It caught me out as well. Poorly named methods - shame on you Apple!

Answer (score 5):

Actually there's a quite easy way to do that:

```
if let volumeSliderView = volumeView.subviews.first as? UISlider {
    volumeSliderView.minimumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_music_volume_min")
    volumeSliderView.maximumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_music_volume_max")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the minimum and maximum value images for MPVolumeView via appearance methods. Here's how to do it in **Objective-C**:

If you only support iOS 9.0+:

```
[[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MPVolumeView class]]] setMinimumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeDown"]];
[[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MPVolumeView class]]] setMaximumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeUp"]];
```

Or for any iOS version after 5.0:

```
if( [UISlider respondsToSelector:@selector(appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:)] )
{
   [[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MPVolumeView class]]] setMinimumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeDown"]];
   [[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MPVolumeView class]]] setMaximumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeUp"]];
}
else
{
   [[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPVolumeView class], nil] setMinimumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeDown"]];
   [[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPVolumeView class], nil] setMaximumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeUp"]];
}
```

In **Swift**:

```
UISlider.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MPVolumeView.self]).minimumValueImage = UIImage(systemName: "speaker.fill")
UISlider.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MPVolumeView.self]).maximumValueImage = UIImage(systemName: "speaker.wave.3.fill")
```